# Integer overflow when using variables but not when using integers

Tags: r, variables

I am trying to multiply 2 numbers together. I am aware that R has a limit for integer size, but from the console, when I manually multiply the numbers, I get a result.

However, when I use *variables* containing those exact numbers, and I multiply *those* together, I get a `NAs produced by integer overflow` error:

[image]

Why is this? Are the variables somehow not properly resolving before being multiplied? I need to be able to use variables, so would it be possible to make it work? Floating point numbers are not an option since precision is needed.

Comment: Compare `125819 * 79263` with `125819L * 79263L`. In the former, you are multiply `numeric`s (real/floating-point), whereas in the latter you are multiplying `integer`s, which is where your problem is. (The `L` at the end of a number forces it to be an `integer`. Try `is.integer(1)` versus `is.integer(1L)`.)

Comment: So this tells me that your `census[c("N","Income")]` are both `integer`, since if either one was a `numeric`, the other would be converted from `integer` to `numeric` and you would have a much higher limit (`.Machine$double.xmax`, versus the integer limit of `.Machine$integer.max`).